# Seeking Guidance on Variable Creation from Wide Format to Indicate Timing of Variables

Tags: r, data.table

In this following subset of [HCUP data](https://hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/nis/tools/stats/FileSpecifications_NIS_2012_Core.TXT), there is an indicator for each procedure within the hospital course of stay based on ICD codes. Each pr column has its corresponding prday column, indicating the timing of each procedure (PR) in a given day (PRDAY). I want to know which procedure occur before the other

I created an indicator for certain ICD values based on pr columns. Specifically, I'm interested in variables named 'var1' and 'var2' and their timing in relation to 'measure1' and 'measure2'. I'm currently stuck on creating the following variables:

> var1_before_measure_1: if prday for var1 <= (less/equal) prday for measure1, then 1, else 0
>
> var1_before_measure_2: if prday for var1 <= prday for measure2, then 1, else 0
>
> var1_after_measure_1: if prday for var1 > (more than) prday for measure1
>
> var1_after_measure_2:if prday for var1 > prday for measure1
>
> var2_before_measure_1: if prday for var2 <= prday for measure1
>
> var2_before_measure_2: if prday for var2 <= prday for measure2
>
> var2_after_measure_1:if prday for var2 > prday for measure1
>
> var2_after_measure_2:if prday for var2 > prday for measure2

​

I would appreciate any insight and help.

Here is my code so far:

```
require(tidyverse) #> Loading required package: tidyverse 

df <- structure(list(pr1 = c("3531",   "0066", "3761", "3523", "3524", "3524", "3523", "3524", "3521",   "3613"), pr2 = c("3597", "3768", "3597", "8856", "8856", "311",   "3611", "3611", "3721", "3523"), pr3 = c("0066", "3723", "8872",   "3761", "3613", "9672", "3961", "3961", "3523", "3722"), pr4 = c("9960",   "3761", "4223", "3768", "3615", "3761", "3964", "3964", "3761",   "3531"), pr5 = c("3893", "3597", "", "8872", "3761", "3611",   "9920", "0017", "3961", "3761"), pr6 = c("3961", "3531", "",   "3961", "8872", "3615", "0017", "8872", "9604", "0066"), pr7 = c("3722",   "", "", "9960", "3961", "3749", "8964", "9672", "3404", "8856"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ), pr8 = c("8853", "", "", "3893", "8872", "3532", "9671", "9904",   "8872", "3964"), pr9 = c("0041", "", "", "3723", "", "3957",   "3995", "9907", "9390", "3606"), pr10 = c("8856", "", "", "3891",   "", "387", "3893", "9905", "9904", "0040"), pr11 = c("9604",   "", "", "8872", "", "8872", "", "9915", "9962", "0045"), pr12 = c("",   "", "", "9604", "", "3961", "", "3324", "9671", "9671"), pr13 = c("",   "", "", "9671", "", "3961", "", "8964", "8872", "9604"), pr14 = c("",   "", "", "", "", "3322", "", "9604", "8872", "8872"), pr15 = c("",   "", "", "", "", "3404", "", "", "3897", ""), prday1 = c(1, 1,   2, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 12, 0), prday2 = c(1, 1, 2, 7, 0, 43, 0, 0,   0, 0), prday3 = c(0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), prday4 = c(6,   1, 2, 12, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), prday5 = c(0, 1, NA, 8, 0, 3, 0,   0, 0, 0), prday6 = c(1, 1, NA, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 14, 0), prday7 = c(0,   NA, NA, 12, 0, 3, 0, 0, 16, 0), prday8 = c(0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 3,   0, 0, 6, 0), prday9 = c(0, NA, NA, 7, NA, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0), prday10 = c(0,   NA, NA, 0, NA, 43, 1, 1, 2, 0), prday11 = c(7, NA, NA, 5, NA,   3, NA, 3, 15, 0), prday12 = c(NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, 3, NA, 10,   14, 1), prday13 = c(NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, 3, NA, 10, 1, 1), prday14 = c(NA,   NA, NA, NA, NA, 43, NA, 10, 6, 7), prday15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,   NA, 18, NA, NA, 9, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame") 

var_1_code<-c("3523", "3524") 
var_2_code<-c("3597") 
measure_1_code<-c("3761") 
measure_2_code<-c("3768")   

find_icd10=function(x) {if_any(starts_with("pr"),# apply ifelse() to columns start with `pr`
  ~ str_detect(.x, x),1,0)} #use str_detect() to find  values within all `pr` columns 

## `code` function aims at allowing multiple values to pass to find_icd10 ## e.g.  ## > mutate(df, icd3509=find_icd10 (code("^3501|^3502|^3509"))) 
code      = function(x) {paste(paste0(rep("^"), # this will add ^ to the begning of each element of the vector, so a value from the middle of a long cell won't be included by mistake                                      
 x), collapse = "|")} # this will allow evaluating multiple elements in a vector without errors from str_detect()   

df<-df %>% mutate(
var_1=find_icd10(code(var_1_code)),  
var_2=find_icd10(code(var_2_code)),  
measure_1=find_icd10(code(measure_1_code)),  
measure_2=find_icd10(code(measure_2_code)), 

# var1_before_measure_1  # var1_before_measure_2  # var1_after_measure_1  # var1_after_measure_2  # var2_before_measure_1  # var2_before_measure_2  # var2_after_measure_1  # var2_after_measure_2
)  
df $var_1 %>% table #> . #> TRUE  #>    7
df $var_2 %>% table #> . #> FALSE  TRUE  #>     2     3 
df $measure_1 %>% table #> . #> TRUE  #>    7 
df $measure_2 %>% table #> . #> FALSE  TRUE  #>     2     2
```

Created with [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/)

I would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance in creating these variables.

Comment: Can you say more about how the values in columns like `prday6` "indicate the timing of each procedure (PR)"? Does that mean `pr6` occurred at hour 1, or it took 1 hour, or what? It seems to me this would probably be simpler and more maintainable in long form, but it's not clear to me what logic drives the expected results.

Comment: For instance, I see var_1_code 3523 occurs in `pr1` of the 4th row, corresponding to a value of 8 in the `prday_1` column. I don't see var_1_code 3524 in that row. Row 4 has measure_1_code 3761 in the `pr3` column, which corresponds to a value of 8 in the `prday_3`. Is that the right mapping, and if so what result do you want for that case?

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring. The timing indicates day variation only. I should have mentioned (will edit above) that if the variable and the measure in the same day, then our assumption is that the variable occurred first. So for observation #4, the patient should be `var1_before_measure_1`==TRUE